# Excel Formatting in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI jars to write excel in Java.

For the below code(referred from other websites), it uses HSSFCellUtil.java class from poi-contrib.jar. This jar doesn't come in the latest release of poi-3.14.jar.

I am getting compile time error at HSSFCellUtil.DATA_FORMAT. Can anyone suggest me the alternative for Excel Formatting.

```
HSSFCellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, workbook,
                    HSSFCellUtil.DATA_FORMAT,
                    format.getFormat("($#,##0.00);($#,##0.00)"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil`

```
DataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();
CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, workbook, CellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, dataFormat.getFormat("$#,##0.00;$#,##0.00"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil` and it works

Replace

```
CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, workbook, HSSFCellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, dataFormat.getFormat("$#,##0.00;$#,##0.00"));
```

with this

```
CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, workbook, CellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, dataFormat.getFormat("$#,##0.00;$#,##0.00"));
```